# Visual Studio 2008 - HTML editing freezes the IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

I have Visual Studio 2008 and recently, whenever I start editing a HTM or HTML page, the IDE freezes.

I then need to end the process via the process explorer. I have uninstalled Resharper and reinstalled VS2008 but no luck. Any other ideas that do not involve doing a clean install of Windows 7?

Comment: What other extensions/plugins do you have installed? - e.g Powershell commands.

Comment: I only installed Resharper. Problems started after I installed v5 of Resharper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem with Resharper which I managed to solve by uninstalling Resharper and then going on a hunt through the hard drive to delete all of the directories which weren't cleared down by the uninstall process. The directories were named Resharper or JetBrains or similar and in various places on the hard drive.

The usual "at your own risk" warnings apply!

Comment: sadly this has not solved my problem :(

Comment: Darn, we had this problem when we started MVC development combined with ReSharper, but hopefully killing all traces of ReSharper would take this out of the picture. I think we got round the problem temporarily by changing the default editor which the HTML files were opened in, might be worth a try?

Answer (score 0):

This has been a problem for years in vs.net, I've seen it all the way back to even vs.net 2003